# My python program keeps returning "KeyError: 20"

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keyerror

I have written a program in python which is supposed to return the highest scoring player for each level, however it keeps returning "KeyError: 20" for line 69 ( P_L1=players_TS[H_L1] ), and I can't work out how to fix this. In my code I open a text file called "playerScores.txt" which is formatted like this:
Moon,3,15
StarPlayer,2,18
Ellie,5,9
etc.
Here is my code:

```
    print("The highest scorers for each leve are:\n")
    PS3=open("PlayerScores.txt","r").read().split("\n")
    level1_scores=[]
    players_TS={}
    level2_scores=[]
    players_T2={}
    level3_scores=[]
    players_T3={}
    level4_scores=[]
    players_T4={}
    level5_scores=[]
    players_T5={}

    for line in PS3:
        lines=line.split(",")
        player=lines[0]
        level=lines[1]
        score=lines[2]

        erros=open("scoreboard_errorlog.text","w")

        if int(score)>20:
            errors.write(score)
        if int(level)>5:
            errors.write(level)

        if int(level)==1:
            level1_scores.append(int(score))
            players_TS.setdefault(score,[]).append(player)
        if int(level)==2:
            level2_scores.append(int(score))
            players_T2.setdefault(score,[]).append(player)
        if int(level)==3:
            level3_scores.append(int(score))
            players_T3.setdefault(score,[]).append(player)
        if int(level)==4:
            level4_scores.append(int(score))
            players_T4.setdefault(score,[]).append(player)
        if int(level)==5:
            level5_scores.append(int(score))
            players_T5.setdefault(score,[]).append(player)

    H_L1=max(level1_scores)
    P_L1=players_TS[H_L1]
    H_L2=max(level2_scores)
    P_L2=players_T2[H_L2]
    H_L3=max(level3_scores)
    P_L3=players_T3[H_L3]
    H_L4=max(level4_scores)
    P_L4=players_T4[H_L4]
    H_L5=max(level5_scores)
    P_L5=players_T5[H_L5]

    print("Level\tPlayer name\tScore\nLevel 1\t",P_L1,"\t",H_L1,"\nLevel 2\t",P_L2,"\t",H_L2,"\nLevel 3\t",P_L3,"\t",H_L3,"\nLevel 4\t",P_L4,"\t",H_L4,"\nLevel 5\t",P_L5,"\t",H_L5)
```

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You could start by identifying where the error occurs.

Comment: One of `erros=open(..` and `errors.write(...` is a typo.

Comment: @ScottHunter  Sorry I forgot to specify - it's line 69 (P_L1=players_TS[H_L1])

Comment: You appear to be putting the *integer* `20` in `level1_scores`, but using the *string* `"20"` as the key in `players_TS`. Thus, when you try to use the value of `H_L1` as a key in `players_TS`, you get the error because `20 != "20"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises here:

```
if int(level)==1:
    level1_scores.append(int(score))
    players_TS.setdefault(score,[]).append(player)
```

Suppose `score == "20"`. You are adding the *integer* `20` to `level1_scores`, but using the *string* `"20"` as a key in `players_TS`. Then, when you get to these lines

```
H_L1=max(level1_scores)
P_L1=players_TS[H_L1]
```

`H_L1` is the integer value `20`, but all the keys in `players_TS` are strings like `"20"`. Since `20 != "20"`, a `KeyError` results.

Likely, you want to have `score` (and `level`, for that matter) be an integer throughout, so convert it once immediately after you parse it, then use `score` as is in the remainder of the loop.

```
for line in PS3:
    lines = line.split(",")
    player = lines[0]
    level = int(lines[1])
    score = int(lines[2])

    with open("scoreboard_errorlog.text","w") as errors:

        if score > 20:
            errors.write(score)
        if level > 5:
            errors.write(level)

    if level == 1:
        level1_scores.append(score)
        players_TS.setdefault(score,[]).append(player)
    elif level == 2:
        level2_scores.append(score)
        players_T2.setdefault(score,[]).append(player)
    elif level == 3:
        level3_scores.append(score)
        players_T3.setdefault(score,[]).append(player)
    elif level == 4:
        level4_scores.append(score)
        players_T4.setdefault(score,[]).append(player)
    elif level == 5:
        level5_scores.append(score)
        players_T5.setdefault(score,[]).append(player)

    H_L1 = max(level1_scores)
    P_L1 = players_TS[H_L1]
    H_L2 = max(level2_scores)
    P_L2 = players_T2[H_L2]
    H_L3 = max(level3_scores)
    P_L3 = players_T3[H_L3]
    H_L4 = max(level4_scores)
    P_L4 = players_T4[H_L4]
    H_L5 = max(level5_scores)
    P_L5 = players_T5[H_L5]
```

However, you should also be using `dict`s to store a lot of this data, rather than individually named variables.

```
level_scores = {level: [] for level in range(1,6)}
players = {}
for line in PS3:
    lines = line.split(",")
    player = lines[0]
    level = int(lines[1])
    score = int(lines[2])

    # Use append mode, or you overwrite the file each time through the loop
    with open("scoreboard_errorlog.text", "a") as errors:

        if score > 20:
            errors.write(score)
        if level > 5:
            errors.write(level)
            continue

    level_scores[level].append(score)
    players[level].setdefault(score,[]).append(player)


H = {}
P = {}
for level in range(1,6):
    H[level] = max(level_scores[level])
    P[level] = players[level][H[level]]
```